# Entity Framework Entity SQL vs Query builder methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Query a Conceptual Model.

I know in EF exists 3 option for querying:

- Linq to Entity
- Entity SQL
- Query builder methods

Here an example of code for the last two:

```
#region Query Entity Sql
string queryJob4 = @"SELECT VALUE myJobs FROM CmsJobs AS myJobs WHERE myJobs.JobId = @id";
ObjectQuery<CmsJob> queryJobs4 = new ObjectQuery<CmsJob>(queryJob4, context);
queryJobs4.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("id", 58));
#endregion

#region Query Builder method
ObjectQuery<CmsJob>queryJob5 = context.CmsJobs.Where("it.JobId == @id", new ObjectParameter("id",66));
#endregion
```

I would like to know:

- In which environment it is more appropriate one way to another and why?
- What do you use and why?

Thanks guys for your opinions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq to Entity is the easier way to build most queries and it's strongly typed, so if you could use Linq To Entity, I would use this as the first choice. However, there are certain situations that you cannot use Linq to Entity, then you have to use Entity SQL or Query builder methods.

One point is that if you want to use Entity Framework outside of VB or C# programs, you may not be able to use LINQ to Entities.

Comment: pay attention that the compilation of the Liq to Entity expression also comes with a cost.  Entity SQL cut that cost.

Comment: @VdesmedT: [citation needed]. Do you mean to imply that EF favors Entity SQL over all others and internally converts Linq-to-Entites statically-typed queries into an Entity SQL string and then proceeds to parse and recompile that string BACK into a command tree expression for execution? That seems a little overkill to me, but I'm just asking if you have a source to back up that assertion.

Comment: "Queries against the Entity Framework are represented by command tree queries, which execute against the object context. LINQ to Entities converts Language-Integrated Queries (LINQ) queries to command tree queries, executes the queries against the Entity Framework, and returns objects that can be used by both the Entity Framework and LINQ." [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx). Nowhere does that imply that LINQ-to-Entities queries are converted into Entity SQL so I don't see how you can assert that Entity SQL can be less costly.

Answer (score 2):

Most of my code uses Linq because thats what EF is essentially about. I'm switching to my own SQL only if I suspect the EF to build queries which are not performant enough. My opinion is that if you write more QueryBuilder-stuff than using Linq, EF might be the wrong technology for that particular project. HTH.